# Render dynamic text based on the time of day - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display a different message in my template, depending on the time of day. In this specific app, I want to indicate premarket, open market, and aftermarket for the US stock exchange.

Currently, I'm displaying the current time.

Here's what I'm using in my template.

```
<div class="score clock">
     <span class="score-title">Current Time</span>
     <span class="score-stat time">{{ time | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}</span>
     <span class="score-stat-post">{{ time | date: 'M.d.yy' }}</span>
</div>
```

Here's what I have in my component file.

```
export class ScoreCardsComponent implements OnInit{
  score$: Observable<any[]>;
  time = new Date();

  constructor(private updatesService: LiveUpdatesService) {
    this.score$ = this.updatesService.getScore();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.time = new Date();
      }, 1000);
  }

}
```

I want to make it so the .score-title element is dynamic. For example, 9-9:30AM would show "Premarket," 9:30AM-4:00PM would show "Open," 4:00PM-6:00PM would show "Aftermarket," and the remaining time would show "Closed."

I'm very new to Angular, so any direction on this would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new custom pipe to handle this. Here's a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-timer) on stackblitz.

Your template will look like:

```html
<div class="score clock">
     <div class="score-title">Current Time - {{ time | timerLabel }}</div>
     <div class="score-stat time">{{ time | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}</div>
     <div class="score-stat-post">{{ time | date: 'M.d.yy' }}</div>
</div>
```

The `timerLabel` is your custom pipe that will render the correct string.

Your pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "timerLabel"
})
export class TimerLabelPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(dateTime: Date): string {
    // const dateTime = new Date('2019-11-08T18:38:16.001Z');

    const utcHours = dateTime.getUTCHours();
    const utcMins = dateTime.getUTCMinutes();

    if (utcHours >= 18 || utcHours < 9) {
      return "Closed";
    }

    if (utcHours >= 16) {
      return "Aftermarket";
    }

    if (utcHours === 9 && utcMins < 31) {
      return "Premartket";
    }

    return "Open";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach? Use the function to set a string in your interval if it really has to happen in real time.

```
getStatus() {
    const hour = new Date().getHours();
    const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    const total = hour * 60 + minutes;

    if (hour >= 9 && total < (9 * 60 + 30)) {
        return 'Premarket';
    } else if (total >= (9 * 60 + 30) && hour < 16) {
        return 'Open';
    } else if (hour >= 16 && hour < 18) {
        return 'Aftermarket';
    } else {
        return 'Closed';
    }
}
```

Comment: consider refactoring this to a pipe instead. In this case you would have to do `{{ getStatus() }}`.  It's generally not advised to call methods in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new date pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: 'dateTitlePipe' })
export class DateTitlePipe implements PipeTransform {
    // adding a default format in case you don't want to pass the format
    // then 'yyyy-MM-dd' will be used
    transform(date: Date | string): string {
        date = new Date(date);  // if orginal type was a string
        if(// Date between something)
            return 'Title you want to show'
        }
    }
}
```

You can check time by doing something like this:

```
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
if (hours == 9 && minutes <= 30) {
    return "Pre Market"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with observables. And since @user3153298 has already provided a great way to track the time, without the need of any additional libraries, you could do it like this...

```
  import { interval } from 'rxjs';

  yourMessage: string;

  //emit value in sequence every 1 second
  source = interval(1000);
  subscribe: any


  constructor() {
    this.source.subscribe(() => {
      const hour = new Date().getHours();
      const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
      const total = hour * 60 + minutes;

      if (hour >= 9 && total < (9 * 60 + 30)) {
        this.yourMessage = 'Premarket';
      } else if (total >= (9 * 60 + 30) && hour < 16) {
        this.yourMessage = 'Open';
      } else if (hour >= 16 && hour < 18) {
        this.yourMessage = 'Aftermarket';
      } else {
        this.yourMessage = 'Closed';
      }
    });
  }
```